# Meaning of "je" in "standen in Abständen von je etwa 250 Metern"

Tags: meaning

From *Der Spiegel*:

> Beobachtungstürme standen in Abständen von je etwa 250 Metern.

Does it mean

> Observation towers stood approximately 250 meters from each other.

?

I'm not sure what **je** means here -- it doesn't seem to correspond to any [meaning](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/je) in the dictionary.

Comment: It means that there were 3 towers at most :P

Comment: @Grantwalzer, ha, schön. Aber dass Du die Erde für eine Scheibe hältst...

Comment: @boaten, maybe you should get a better dictionary.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz, das geht auch mit 4 Türmen, aber nicht beim Durchmesser der Erde. Auf einem Asteroiden, vielleicht...

Comment: Oh peinlich, die 250m hatte ich schon wieder vergessen. Ursprünglich wollte ich auch nur schreiben, Granatwalzer hätte eine Dimension vergessen. Wir brauchen einen steilen Berg.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your translation is correct. *Je* is short for *jeweils*. It is used when a certain fact [applies to each member](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/je_jemals_abhaengig_von#Bedeutung2b) of a given set. In the example the meaning would be probably also clear without it, but one could also think of two groups of towers that stand very close together in each group, and only the distance between the two groups is 250m. The *je* excludes this interpretation - without real need, it's more a habit to use it.

Comment: "Je" is not necessary because of "in Abständen" (in contrast to "im Abstand von"). If the sentence were "Die Beobachtungstürme standen 250m voneinander entfernt", then "je" becomes essential.

Answer (score 3):

The online dictionary that you linked gives the correct translation: **each**

> Observations towers stood in distances of approximately 250 meters **each**.

The word *je* refers to the *Abstände* as does *each* refer to the *distances*.

Your translation gives the correct sense of the sentence but changes its grammatical structure a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Auf jede Strecke von 250 Metern kommt ein Wachturm.